# HTML Audio Tag Continues Playing Audio on Page Change

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app that contains an audio tag on one page.  I have a check that if a boolean is set then the audio will autoplay on page load.  This works as expected, but when I navigate to ANY other page on the site (even ones without audio tags) the same audio autoplays from the beginning.

If I remove the autoplay option, the problem goes away, but I would like to keep this feature to autoplay if the boolean is true.  Also this problem only happens when navigating to different pages on the same site.  If I go to a different website, the audio stops.

Here is the code for the audio tag:

```html
  <audio src="<%= audio_path mp3_link%>"
                  type="audio/mpeg"
                  id=<%= "#{title_id}" %>
                  onplay=javascriptFunction()
                  controls <% if play_audio_on_load %> autoplay <% end %> >
```

EDIT:
  After some experimentation, I realize this problem persists whenever autoplay is enabled, not just when it is triggered by a boolean.  I am much more interested in WHERE the audio is actually coming from than how to solve my particular problem. It just doesn't make sense to me because the newly loaded pages don't contain any audio tags and yet the audio plays.

UPDATE / SOLUTION:
I realize that my problem came from trying to do something unnecessary in the first place.  What I was trying to do was update my database and then reload the page and play the audio from where it left off.  What I didn't realize I could do was just update the database without reloading the page.  This keeps my audio playing and doesn't create the problem from before.

I still don't know what could have possibly caused the audio to keep playing, so if anyone knows the reason / solution please post it here in case someone else has this problem in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and the reason was turbo-links. Turbolinks interfere with the browsers viewpoint of a page.

See https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks :

> "Turbolinks intercepts all clicks on  links to the same domain. When you click an eligible link, Turbolinks prevents the browser from following it. Instead, Turbolinks changes the browser’s URL using the History API, requests the new page using XMLHttpRequest, and then renders the HTML response.
>
> During rendering, Turbolinks replaces the current `<body>` element outright and merges the contents of the `<head>` element. The JavaScript window and document objects, and the HTML `<html>` element, persist from one rendering to the next."

This seem to interfere with the `autoplay` attribute of the `<audio>` tag, which is still active.

One fix is to disable all turbolinks reachable from the specific page, i.e. inside all related partials, so that a true reload of the linked page is done.

Example:

```
    <%= link_to "Home", root_path, 'data-turbolinks':false %>
```

Another possibility is to make turbo-links reload specific pages, by incorporating the following into the header of that page:

```html
<head>
  ...
  <meta name="turbolinks-visit-control" content="reload">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    $.each($('video, audio'), function(i,e){ e.pause() })
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your feedback, but this solution did not work for me.  I added this code to my application.js file, and then inside a <script> </script> inside the actual views, neither of which worked.  I also attempted the similar window.addEventListener("beforeunload", ...) and got the same failure.

Comment: can you put an alert inside the callback function and see if its beeing called on page refresh

Comment: I added an alert to the function and it seems that it is not being called.  Is there a particular place that it needs to go in the view? Currently I just have it in a <script> tag at the end of my *.html.erb file.

Comment: try $(window).bind("beforeunload", functon(){})

Comment: When I use $(window).bind(...), the function gets triggered and the alerts are displayed, but the problem persists.

Comment: see if $('audio')[0].pause() pauses first playing audio element

Comment: When I do that I get the following error in the console:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pause' of undefined.  Which makes sense because when I inspect the source there are no audio tags on the page.

Comment: it sems the audio element is not there. somehow get the handle of audio element, you can try document.getElementById('your_audio_ag_id').pause() also